# LiveData with shared preferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, android-livedata

I have a settings screen where I am setting some values. When I set those values it gets saved in shared preferences and these values are needed in my
request to the network api call as parameters.

Now I can use a listener for shared preferences in my activity then make an api call and get fresh data, but I want to use this with LiveData.

How can I listen for changes in the shared preferences using LiveData and then make the network call using the new parameters.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rharter/1df1cd72ce4e9d1801bd2d49f2a96810

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Java Code](https://gist.github.com/idish/f46a8327da7f293f943a5bda31078c95) by [Idish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203043/idish), though he commented here, but not sure, why he didn't add it as answer.

Pasting the same code below:

```
public abstract class SharedPreferenceLiveData<T> extends LiveData<T> {

SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
String key;
public T defValue;

public SharedPreferenceLiveData(SharedPreferences prefs, String key, T defValue) {
    this.sharedPrefs = prefs;
    this.key = key;
    this.defValue = defValue;
}

private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (SharedPreferenceLiveData.this.key.equals(key)) {
            setValue(getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue));
        }
    }
};
abstract T getValueFromPreferences(String key, T defValue);

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    super.onActive();
    setValue(getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue));
    sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    sharedPrefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
    super.onInactive();
}
public SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean> getBooleanLiveData(String key, Boolean defaultValue) {
    return new SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(sharedPrefs,key, defaultValue);
}
}
```

SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData class

```
public class SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData extends SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean>{

public SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(SharedPreferences prefs, String key, Boolean defValue) {
    super(prefs, key, defValue);
}

@Override
Boolean getValueFromPreferences(String key, Boolean defValue) {
    return sharedPrefs.getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

}
```

Calling this like the below code mentioned in this [link](https://gist.github.com/idish/f46a8327da7f293f943a5bda31078c95#gistcomment-2881671):

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 SharedPreferenceStringLiveData sharedPreferenceStringLiveData = new SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(preferences, "cid", "");
 sharedPreferenceStringLiveData.getStringLiveData("cid", "").observe(this, cid -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Change in CID "+cid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 });
```

Again if using a Preference Helper class, the class can be called as below:
Just a sample:

```
public class PreferenceManager {
private SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData sharedPreferenceLiveData;

public SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData getSharedPrefs(){
        return sharedPreferenceLiveData;
    }

public void setSharedPreferences(String key, boolean value) {

        SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCE,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userDetails.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.apply();
        sharedPreferenceLiveData = new SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(userDetails,key,value);
    }
}
```

And in the activity class call it as below:
Create an object:

```
SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData sharedPreferenceLiveData;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferenceLiveData = preferenceManager.getSharedPrefs();
}
```

And observe it as follows:

```
sharedPreferenceLiveData.getBooleanLiveData(PreferenceKey.KEY_LOCATION_PERMISSION,false).observe(this,check->{
        if(check){
            setPermissionGranted(check);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case using SharedPreferenceStringLiveData. For the same value (example, first storing "First" and second time also string "First") , the onSharedPreferenceChanged won't call.

Comment: One can Overrride getVale() as well and return value directly from shared preference. It will be helpful if someone wants to check value of livedata at a given time but do not want to observe it. 

//Add this in your SharedPreferenceLiveData class
override fun getValue(): T? {
     return getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)
}

Answer (score 40):

The following awesome piece of code is LiveData Implementation of SharedPreference. It works perfectly.

```
package com.chargingwatts.chargingalarm.util.preference;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.content.SharedPreferences

abstract class SharedPreferenceLiveData<T>(val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences,
                                           val key: String,
                                           val defValue: T) : LiveData<T>() {

    private val preferenceChangeListener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
        if (key == this.key) {
            value = getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)
        }
    }

    abstract fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: T): T

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        value = getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)
        sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        sharedPrefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener)
        super.onInactive()
    }
}

class SharedPreferenceIntLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Int) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Int>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Int): Int = sharedPrefs.getInt(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: String) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<String>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: String): String = sharedPrefs.getString(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Boolean) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Boolean): Boolean = sharedPrefs.getBoolean(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceFloatLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Float) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Float>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Float): Float = sharedPrefs.getFloat(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceLongLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Long) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Long>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Long): Long = sharedPrefs.getLong(key, defValue)
}

class SharedPreferenceStringSetLiveData(sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, key: String, defValue: Set<String>) :
        SharedPreferenceLiveData<Set<String>>(sharedPrefs, key, defValue) {
    override fun getValueFromPreferences(key: String, defValue: Set<String>): Set<String> = sharedPrefs.getStringSet(key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.intLiveData(key: String, defValue: Int): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Int> {
    return SharedPreferenceIntLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.stringLiveData(key: String, defValue: String): SharedPreferenceLiveData<String> {
    return SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.booleanLiveData(key: String, defValue: Boolean): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Boolean> {
    return SharedPreferenceBooleanLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.floatLiveData(key: String, defValue: Float): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Float> {
    return SharedPreferenceFloatLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.longLiveData(key: String, defValue: Long): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Long> {
    return SharedPreferenceLongLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}

fun SharedPreferences.stringSetLiveData(key: String, defValue: Set<String>): SharedPreferenceLiveData<Set<String>> {
    return SharedPreferenceStringSetLiveData(this, key, defValue)
}
```

Comment: Here's a java code version of this beautiful piece: https://gist.github.com/idish/f46a8327da7f293f943a5bda31078c95

Comment: For someone who is wondering why `sharedPrefs.getString(key, defValue)` could be null, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57323323/9317258) explains it well.

Comment: This can be improved by having the abstract class override `getValue()` and returning non-nullable `super.getValue() ?: getValueFromPreferences(key, defValue)`, so non-nullable `value` can also be retrieved directly without observing.

Answer (score 5):

Android recently released [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#typed-datastore) which is:

> Jetpack DataStore is a data storage solution that allows you to store key-value pairs or typed objects with protocol buffers. DataStore uses Kotlin coroutines and Flow to store data asynchronously, consistently, and transactionally.
>
> If you're currently using SharedPreferences to store data, consider migrating to DataStore instead.

So here is the breakdown:

In the `build.gradle` of the project:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha04"
}
```

The database class would look like:

```
class SettingsSharedPreference private constructor(context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.createDataStore(name = "settings")

    companion object {

        val SCREEN_ORIENTATION = preferencesKey<String>("screen_orientation")

        @Volatile
        private var instance: SettingsSharedPreference? = null

        private val lock = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(lock) {
            instance ?: SettingsSharedPreference(context).also { instance = it }
        }
    }

    val screenOrientationFlow: Flow<String> = dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[SCREEN_ORIENTATION] ?: "landscape"
        }

    //TODO: You should use enum for screenOrientation, this is just an example
    suspend fun setScreenOrientation(screenOrientation: String) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[SCREEN_ORIENTATION] = screenOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

In the Activity:

```
val settingsSharedPreference by lazy {
    SettingsSharedPreference.invoke(this)
}
...
settingsSharedPreference.setScreenOrientation("portrait")    
...
settingsSharedPreference.screenOrientationFlow.asLiveData().observe(this) { screenOrientation ->
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works in Kotlin and RxJava. Waiting for it in plain Java with Jetpack Lifecycle/ Guava

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your network request is already providing you a LiveData class. For example with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and a CallAdapter like [LiveDataCallAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapter.kt).

Once you have the last observed value by either:

- Applying a listener for shared preferences `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, as you already mentioned, to update a [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData)
- Or using a SharedPreferences LiveData like [rharter/SharedPreferenceLiveData.kt](https://gist.github.com/rharter/1df1cd72ce4e9d1801bd2d49f2a96810)

Then you can apply the previous LiveData to either:

- A [Transformations.switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations) as in [UserViewModel.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt) (related part quoted below)
- Or as parameter for [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) addSource method.

This is the related example for the Transformations.switchMap in [UserViewModel.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt):

```
private val _login = MutableLiveData<String>()
val login: LiveData<String>
    get() = _login
val repositories: LiveData<Resource<List<Repo>>> = Transformations
    .switchMap(_login) { login ->
        if (login == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create()
        } else {
            repoRepository.loadRepos(login)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've create a pure kotlin lib to do this - https://github.com/Jintin/PreferencesExtension

All we need to do is something like:

```kotlin
val preferenceLiveData = preference.liveData<String>(MY_KEY)

preferenceLiveData.observe(this) {
    // get update here
}
```

And sure the preferenceLiveData can be inside ViewModel and let Activity/Fragment observe it.
Check out the example here:
[Activity](https://github.com/Jintin/PreferencesExtension/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jintin/preferencesextension/app/MainActivity.kt),
[ViewModel](https://github.com/Jintin/PreferencesExtension/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jintin/preferencesextension/app/MainViewModel.kt)

Answer (score 1):

i see your challenge is calling Shared Preferences Value when API Calling in ViewModel or LiveData.

You may define your shared preference as global in Application class ( so it will be global)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   public static AppPreferences shared_preference;

   /*On Create Application Create AppPreferences*/
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     shared_preference = AppPreferences.getInstance(this);
   }
}
```

And you may update or save value by calling Shared Preference in your ViewModel

```
/*Save to Shared Preferences*/
MyApplication.shared_preference.setLogin(true);
```

Wish this help you, cause i see your problem there, This is works for me and able to insert param in API Call.

Comment: It is not observing changes. He wants to observe whenever SharedPreference value is changed , and perform some action then.

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency in **build.gradle(:app)**

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6"  // replace with updated version 
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6"// replace with updated version
```

Add Below code inyYour preference **class/utils**

```
private var mPrefs: SharedPreferences =
        mContext.getSharedPreferences(AppConstant.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

 private val _constSate = MutableStateFlow(mPrefs.getBoolean(IS_NOTIFY,false))

// function for set data to preference and add to Stateflow. 

fun setData(isNotify: Boolean){
       // mPrefs = instance of your preference 
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_NOTIFY, isNotify).apply()
        _constSate.value = isNotify
    }

//function for get observer/flow/live boolean value 

fun getNotifyFlow() : StateFlow<Boolean> = _constSate
```

//get your observer/flow/live value on other class e.g **MainActivity.class etc..**

```
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{      
     appPreferences.getNotifyFlow().collect{
                   if (it){
                    Log.d("jai","true")
                   }else{
                     Log.d("jai","false")
                   }
                }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can organize all your SharedPreferences value in single LiveData

```
public class SharedPreferencesLiveData extends LiveData<ObservableArrayMap<String, Object>> {

    private final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference;

    public SharedPreferencesLiveData(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        super(new ObservableArrayMap<String, Object>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Object put(String key, Object value) {
                final Object lastValue = super.get(key);
                if (!Objects.equals(value, lastValue)) {
                    if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value).apply();
                    } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat(key, (Float) value).apply();
                    } else if (value instanceof String) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, (String) value).apply();
                    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(key, (Integer) value).apply();
                    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(key, (Long) value).apply();
                    } else if (value instanceof Set) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(key, (Set<String>) value).apply();
                    } else if (value == null) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).apply();
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value=" + value + " data type not support");
                    }
                    return super.put(key, value);
                } else
                    return lastValue;
            }
        });
        mSharedPreference = sharedPreferences;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        getValue().clear();
        getValue().putAll((SimpleArrayMap<? extends String, ?>) new ArrayMap<String, Object>() {{
            putAll(mSharedPreference.getAll());
        }});
        mSharedPreference.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        mSharedPreference.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(key)) {
                getValue().put(key, sharedPreferences.getAll().get(key));
            } else {
                getValue().remove(key);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

then declare your LiveData of SharedPreferences in your ViewModel

```
public static class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public final SharedPreferencesLiveData sharedPreferenceLiveData = new SharedPreferencesLiveData(getApplication().getSharedPreferences("XXX", 0));

    public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
}
```

then access & update (two-way databinding) your SharedPreferences from XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.xxx.sharedpreferencedatabindingtest.MainActivity.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked='@={((Boolean)viewModel.sharedPreferenceLiveData["XXXX"])}'
            android:text="XXX" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked='@={((Boolean)viewModel.sharedPreferenceLiveData["XXXX"])}'
            android:text="XXX" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="1000"
            android:min="0"
            android:progress='@={(Integer)(viewModel.sharedPreferenceLiveData["YYYY"])}' />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="1000"
            android:min="0"
            android:progress='@={(Integer)(viewModel.sharedPreferenceLiveData["YYYY"])}' />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wondered how to listen for changes in the preferences made in a Preferences activity and it's fragment from `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, but it turned out that if the `MainActivity` is refreshed after pressing the "Up" button then this is not necessary to "subscribe" for changes. In `AndroidManifest`, if `android:launchMode` is set, it should be "standard" (this will cause the `MainActivity` to be refreshed after navigating to it from another activity). Then you can get a preference simply using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` which is accessible from anywhere as described in the documentation.