# What's the point of having a default value in sharedPref.getString?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm accessing my Android apps `SharedPreferences` via

```
private val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`
```

and then attempting to get data from it using

```
val lat: String = sharedPref.getString("MyKey", "Default")
```

But this line gives me an error reading `"Type mismatch. Required String, found String?"`

According to the documentation the second parameter in the getString method says "Value to return if this preference does not exist. **This value may be null.**"

So what's the point of having a default value then if the value can be null? I cannot seem to get the default value to ever be used and the only way I can get my code to work is to use the elvis operator and rewrite my code as:

```
val lat: String = sharedPref.getString("MyKey", "Default") ?: "Default"
```

Which looks ugly. Am I crazy? What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider this in a such way:
Every `String` preference in `SharedPreferences` can **exist** or **not** and can be `null` or **not**. So the code

```
val lat: String = sharedPref.getString("MyKey", "Default") ?: "Not Set"
```

will return:

- `Default` if the preference with this Key doesn't exists (means there is no mapping for this Key)
- `Not Set` if the preference exists, but is `null` (mapping Key to `null` created)
- any other `value` if the preference exists and the value of the mapping isn't `null`.

**Update**

Apparently, SharedPreferences are much less smart I thought it was. Having this code internally:

```
String v = (String)mMap.get(key);
return v != null ? v : defValue;
```

it will return `null` **only** if we'll pass `null` as a default value (and there were no value saved). This means we actually don't need an elvis option and **we will not get `"Not Set"`** value. This method returns nullable value, just because it allows you to pass nullable as a default value.

Comment: your response makes the most sense to me. It just seems strange to me that getInt and getLong cannot be null but getString can

Comment: That's because `getInt`, `getLong`, etc. work with primitive types in Java and so they cannot be `null`,

Comment: this is not correct answer, it returns the default value even it had never saved before with such key.

Comment: @NurseyitTursunkulov, "it had never saved before with such key" = there is no mapping for this Key -> return default value.

Comment: @Demigod we will never get null

Comment: @NurseyitTursunkulov, yes, you're right. We will not get `null`

Answer (score 5):

It's because kotlin Null-Safety is kick in when reading the following code:

```
val lat: String = sharedPref.getString("MyKey", "Default")
```

if you visit the [SharedPreferences](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3e7d977/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java) code, you can see the [following code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3e7d977/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java#257):

```
@Nullable
String getString(String key, @Nullable String defValue);
```

which is give us a probability to use null as `defValue` parameter. So, Kotlin try to guard it and give you the matching error:

> "Type mismatch. Required String, found String?"

You can fix the problem by enabling nullable for your String variable with:

```
val lat: String? = sharedPref.getString("MyKey", "Default")
```

though this against [Kotlin type system purpose](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html):

> Kotlin's type system is aimed at eliminating the danger of null references from code, also known as the The Billion Dollar Mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand how to fix the problem, but my attempts as a developer to solve the billion dollar mistake is to keep the number of nullable variables in my code to a minimum. getInt and getLong cannot be null so why can getString?

Comment: It's because both the `int getInt(String key, int defValue);` and `long getLong(String key, long defValue);` didn't have a nullable default value parameter. You can see at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3e7d977/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java. Be noted that kotlin for Android is depends on the Android api which is in Java. So, kotlin for Android won't be totally safe from null.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` is an abstraction over Key/Value databasing provided by Google, how you use it is up to you. If you dislike this syntax, then create a wrapper or extension for your `getString()`. Just to give an example:

```
fun PreferenceManager.getStringTheFancyWay(key: String, defaultValue: String): String {
    return getString(key, defaultValue) ?: defaultValue
}
val value = getStringTheFancyWay("a", "b")
```

Personally I dislike this, because `null` allows for a better control flow over non-existing keys.

This is how I use SharedPreferences

```
val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
val value = preferences.getString("username", null)
if (value != null) {
    toast("Hello $value")
} else {
    toast("Username not found")
}
```

or

```
preferences.getString("username", null)?.let { username ->
    toast("Hello $username")
}
```

Notice the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The fact is simple, just imagine you haven't saved any value regarding to that key(for your case 'MyKey') and tried to get the value for that key(for your case 'MyKey'). What will SharedPreference return ? It will simply return the default value.

You will see that, you must assign null or any other string to default for String type, 0 or any other int value to default for integer type and true or false default value for bolean type. I hope you got the answer.