# Simple Kotlin Data Save

Tags: android, kotlin, save

I am trying to make a simple Kotlin Class `user` for Android and i would like to save the username to keep it when closing and reopening the application

```
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class User (var username : String){
    private val PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY = "AppPreference"
    private val KEY_USERNAME= "prefUserNameKey"
    private val sharedPref : SharedPreferences = activity?.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun Save(){
        with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString(KEY_USERNAME, username)
        commit()
        }
    }

    fun Load(){
        teamname = sharedPref.getString(KEY_SAVENAME, "Default")?:"Default"
    }
}
```

I have a first question : 
android studio says `sharedPref.getString(KEY_SAVENAME, "Default")` is a `String?`, but then what is the purpose of the default value here then ?

And secondly, my real problem here is that the `activity?` keyword has an unresolved reference.

Comment: `activity?.` will return unresolved reference because nowhere the `User` class is being provided with an activity context. To solve it, simply pass a reference to the activity.

Comment: For using SharedPreferences in Kotlin projects, I can highly recommend KotPref: github.com/chibatching/Kotpref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better practice is to pass shared preference instance when constructing user object because user class shouldn't care how shared preferences is built or about activity:

```
class User (var username : String, private val sharedPref : SharedPreferences){
}
```

Also, when getting shared preference instance, use application context not activity to prevent memory leaks:

```
val sharedPref : SharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE)
val user = User("username", sharedPref)
user.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `sharedPref.getString(KEY_SAVENAME, "Default")` returns a `String?`, because the "Default"- String can be `null`. For more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318576/whats-the-point-of-having-a-default-value-in-sharedpref-getstring).

Secondly, try using

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

to initiate the preference instance.

Comment: Tkanks, i understand for the ```String?```. PreferenceManager is deprecated according to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
         private lateinit var sharedpreferences: SharedPreferences

            companion object {
                val mypreference = "mypref"
                val Name = "nameKey"
            }

       private fun Save(userName : String) {
                val editor = sharedpreferences.edit()
                editor.putString(Name, userName)
                etName.setText("username")
                editor.apply()
            }

          private  fun Get(userName: String) {
                sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

                if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
                    val setString = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, userName)
                    etName.setText(getString)
                }
            }


//Call funtion in onCreate method
            private fun containUserString(){
                sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
                    val setString = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "")
                    etName.setText(getString)
                }
            }
```