# How to pass custom listener from Fragment to VM in MVVM?

Tags: android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewpager, listener, onclicklistener

My app has a bottom nav with 3 Fragments where first one has a ViewPager with tablayout each having their own Fragments.

What I want to do is change the content of fragments of viewpager fragments depending on the selection of Spinner selected.

How do i implement a listener to listen for change in Spinner to change the data calls to repo in each of the ViewModels.

Any other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be ideal solution, but I was able to work it out using SharedPreference and SharedPreference Listener. I also came across LiveData to observe SharedPreference, but this was easier and much simpler. Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410906/observing-sharedpreferences-data)